# Analytical Statistics Question

Tags: statistics

Let X be a unit uniform random variable, i.e., X ∼Unif[0, 1]. Let Y = 2X

(a) Let U = 1[Y ∈ (.5, 1)], and let V = 1[Y ∈ (1.5, 2)].

i. Is U ∼ V ? justify your response.
ii. Does U = V ? justify your response.

(b) Let Z = 2 − Y

i. Is Z ∼ Y ? justify your response.
ii. Does Z = Y ? justify your response.

*These were two questions included in my latest Statistics homework. The problem I'm facing with this is that I don't really understand what the question is asking or what U and V really entail. How can we prove or disprove that these are equal?*

*Any help or guidance on this would be very appreciated :) I'm stumped here.*

Comment: U and V are random variables and not sets. For example U=1 if 0.5<Y<1 zero otherwise. So U's distribution is: 1 with probability 1/2 and 0 with probability 1/2. Can you see what the question is now?

Comment: @zoli The distribution of $Y$ is uniform on $[0,2]$ so $P(U=1)=0.25$.

Answer (score 1):

$U,V$ are not sets, but they are random variable defined as follows 
\begin{align}
U &= 1 &~\text{if}~& Y \in (.5,1), \\
U &= 0 &~~\text{if}~& Y \notin (.5,1),\\
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
V &= 1 &~\text{if}~& Y \in (1.5,2), \\
V &= 0 &~~\text{if}~& Y \notin (1.5,2).\\
\end{align}
So both are discrete random variables with possible values $0$ and $1$. So now all you have to do is to prove that $P(U=1)=P(V=1)$. Since $Y=2X$ we know, that $Y$ has uniform distribution on $[0,2]$, so 
$$P(U=1) = P(Y \in (.5,1)) = \frac{1}{4} =   P(Y \in (1.5,2)) = P(V=1).$$ Can you now do the b.?

Comment: D'oh! This makes a LOT more sense.I'd been sick last class, and I guess this is what I'd missed. Thank you very much. I'll try b on my own now.